# Ant build not able to recognize spanish characters

Tags: apache, ant, selenium

I am having a Selenium project that uses Apache ANT to execute the tests.

In a certain scenario i need to validate a few Spanish texts like "eBay España" i.e. text with accented characters.

When i execute the test normally from my IntelliJ IDEA IDE it runs properly and validates the  Spanish characters appropriately.

But when i try executing the test from Apache ANT console in the IDE , it is not able to recognize the Spanish accented characters.

Check O/P

- **Normal Execution -**

  INFO [main] (VerifySpanishCharacters.java:45) - FIRE FOX DRIVER INSTANTIATED
   INFO [main] (VerifySpanishCharacters.java:46) - SELENIUM DRIVER INSTANTIATED
   INFO [main] (VerifySpanishCharacters.java:47) - https://login.salesforce.com/
  com.cognizant.automation.resources.ExcelSheetUtil.SheetReader@149b290
  eBay España
  áéíóú
   INFO [main] (VerifySpanishCharacters.java:61) - selenium driver closed
- **Apache ANT Execution**

  MESSAGE LOGGED
  [testng]  INFO [pool-2-thread-1] (VerifySpanishCharacters.java:45) - FIRE FOX DRIVER INSTANTIATED
  MESSAGE LOGGED
  [testng]  INFO [pool-2-thread-1] (VerifySpanishCharacters.java:46) - SELENIUM DRIVER INSTANTIATED
  MESSAGE LOGGED
  [testng]  INFO [pool-2-thread-1] (VerifySpanishCharacters.java:47) - https://login.salesforce.com/
  MESSAGE LOGGED
  [testng] com.cognizant.automation.resources.ExcelSheetUtil.SheetReader@7bc899
  MESSAGE LOGGED
  [testng] eBay Espa�
  MESSAGE LOGGED
  [testng] ����
  MESSAGE LOGGED
  [testng]  INFO [pool-2-thread-1] (VerifySpanishCharacters.java:61) - selenium driver closed

Can you please help with a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following link to change the text into UTF8/UTF-16M characters and you can use that characters instead of that text with some escape sequence

http://macchiato.com/unicode/convert.html

Go to this link, in the input box editor give your text, then choose UTF-16M in the dropdown over the output box editor, then click on the button in between input and output box editor, you can get the desired value in the output box editor. you can use the value with the escape sequence in your code.

For example, for the text "eBay España" you will get output as "0065 0042 0061 0079 0020 0045 0073 0070 0061 00F1 0061", you can use this value with escape sequence as "\u0065 \u0042 \u0061 \u0079 \u0020 \u0045 \u0073 \u0070 \u0061 \u00F1 \u0061".

Just try with this...